# Updating properties of JS "class" based on other properties?

Tags: javascript, class, get, physics-engine

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I am trying to create a very simple physics engine for a game type project I am working on. In order to do this, I created what I understand to be the JS equivalent of a class that I can create new copies of for each object I want. The problem is that I want to be able to update a value such as the x position and have this also update things such as the x Middle position (x center of object on screen). I know this is possible by using an object literal and the getter, however I want to be able to create new objects at realtime based on what's on the screen and I couldn't figure out how to use get to make this work. Here's the general idea of what I am trying to do:

```
var object = function (xPos, yPos, width, height) {
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;
  function getXMid (xP) { return xP + width/2; }
  this.xMid = getXMid (this.xPos);
  function getYMid (yP) { return yP + height/2; }
  this.yMid = getYMid (this.yPos);
}

var ball = new object (10, 20, 50, 50);
ball.xPos = 50;
console.log (ball.xMid); // want this to output 75 instead of 45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing one property, and expecting other properties to update, unfortunately it doesn't work that way when the properties hold primitive values.

You could use setters and getters and a function to update the other properties when you set a value

```js
var object = function(xPos, yPos, width, height) {
    this._xPos  = xPos;
    this._yPos  = yPos;
    this.recalc = function() {
     this.xMid = getXMid(this.xPos);
        this.yMid = getYMid(this.yPos);
    }
    
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'xPos', {
        get: function() {
            return this._xPos;
        },
        set: function(v) {
         this._xPos = v;
         this.recalc();
        }
    });

 Object.defineProperty(this, 'yPos', {
        get: function() {
            return this._yPos;
        },
        set: function(v) {
         this._yPos = v;
         this.recalc();
        }
    });
    
    function getXMid(xP) { return xP + width / 2; }
    
    function getYMid(yP) { return yP + height / 2; }
    
    this.recalc();
}

var ball = new object(10, 20, 50, 50);
ball.xPos = 50;
console.log (ball.xMid); // want this to output 75 instead of 45
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work! I'm a little confused on how exactly the setter works though. Where does the v parameter you use come from?

Comment: The only argument the setter gets, is the set value, so `v` is whatever you set `this.xPos = ***` to